# How to divide an array which has array[0] in 4 values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

All values are inserted in arr_type_and_value[0].

I would like to insert each value in as:

```
arr_type_and_value[0] >> 1 value,arr_type_and_value[1]>> 2 value,  arr_type_and_value[2] >> 3 value and arr_type_and_value[3] >> 4 value.
```

How do I do do that?

```
<?
$value="1,2,3,4";   
$arrlst =array();                      
$arrlst =explode(",",$value);  

foreach($arrlst as $relatedlst) {

    $arr_type_and_value=explode(":",$relatedlst);
    print_r($arr_type_and_value); // this got >> Array ( [0] => 1 ) Array ( [0] => 2 ) Array ( [0] => 3 ) Array ( [0] => 4 ); 

    $type= $arr_type_and_value [0]; 
    $value=$arr_type_and_value [1]; 

}        
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
<?php
$value="1,2,3,4";   
// $arrlst =array();                      
$arrlst =explode(",",$value);  
    // print_r($arrlst); 
        foreach($arrlst as $key => $relatedlst) {

            // $arr_type_and_value=explode(":",$relatedlst);
            // print_r($arr_type_and_value); // this got >> Array ( [0] => 1 ) Array ( [0] => 2 ) Array ( [0] => 3 ) Array ( [0] => 4 ); 

            $type_value[$key]= $relatedlst; 
            // $value[$key]=$relatedlst;

            }        
            print_r($type_value); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_map:

```
$arr_type_and_value = array_map(function ($value) {
    return $value[0];
}, $relatedlst );
```